# how do I format my SSD in NTFS before removing it from the old PC for other purposes

Tags: ssd

I want to format my SSD 1T that I have in my old PC before using it an an external Hard Drive.
How do I do in Ubuntu?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://gparted.org/features.php shows Gparted can create an NTFS partition, so I would start gparted, [select the SSD](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-select-device), and [format it for NTFS](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-format-partition).

Answer (score 0):

Is there are reason you need to format it *before* adding it as an external drive? If you are going to be connecting it to a machine running Ubuntu you can just install [GParted](https://gparted.org/) (`sudo apt install gparted`) & format it once it is connected.

If you *need* to format before removing it from your old system, you can download a live GParted image & burn it to an optical disc or USB drive. Then boot your old system from said disc/drive to launch GParted live. There you can use it to format the internal drive to NTFS.

**Note:** If you prefer using the terminal, you can use [GNU parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html) (`sudo apt install parted`).